# Microsoft Outlook Rest API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am trying sync office 365 calendar events with my website for multiple outlook users.

I am referring to the [Write a PHP app to get Outlook mail, calendar, and contacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/php-tutorial#register-the-app) documentation.

As per 'Account requirements' section:

> In order to use the Application Registration Portal, you need either an Office 365 work or school account, or a Microsoft account. If you don't have either of these, you have a number of options:
>
> - Sign up for a new Microsoft account [here](https://signup.live.com/signup?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&ct=1454618383&rver=6.4.6456.0&wp=MBI_SSL_SHARED&wreply=https://mail.live.com/default.aspx&id=64855&cbcxt=mai&bk=1454618383&uiflavor=web&uaid=b213a65b4fdc484382b6622b3ecaa547&mkt=E-US&lc=1033&lic=1).
> - You can obtain an Office 365 subscription in a couple of different ways:
>
>   - You can get a free one-year Office 365 Developer subscription by signing up for the [Office Developer program](http://dev.office.com/devprogram).
>   - You can signup for a [25-user free trial](https://portal.office.com/Signup/Signup.aspx?OfferId=467eab54-127b-42d3-b046-3844b860bebf&dl=O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM&alo=1&lc=1033&ali=1#0) of the Office 365 Business subscription.

So below are my queries,

1. When referring to 'free 25 users', what does it mean exactly?
2. For using this API, do we need to buy office 365 subscription?

Answer (score 0):

In order to register your application in the [Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) (`apps.dev.microsoft.com`), you either need a Microsoft Account (aka an Outlook.com account) or an account in an Azure AD tenant.

You do not need to have a subscription to Office 365 for this (although it would seem pretty valuable to have one if you're going to be writing code that uses an O365 API).

You can obtain a free developer account via the [Office 365 Developer Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/office/profile). This program includes a free 12-month subscription to Office 365 for use in development and testing.

Answer (score -1):

**1) When referring to 'free 25 users', what does it mean exactly?**

If you will go for trial of office 365 subscription, you can have maximum 25 users and 1 month trial period limitation. after that the account will be expired.

**2) For using this API, do we need to buy office 365 subscription?**

If your all outlook users for which you want to sync calendar events are  Microsoft organizational accounts ***(user@organisation.com)*** then you don't need office 365 subscription.
otherwise you will need the one